# How can I convert a generic List<T> to a List?

Tags: c#, generics

How can I convert a generic List to a List?

I am using a `ListCollectionView` and I need to provide it with an `IList` not an `IList<T>`.

I see plenty of examples to convert an `IList` to a `IList<T>`, but not the other way.

Do I just convert it manually (`new List().AddRange(IList<T>`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As `List<T>` implements the `IList` interface, you can simply provide the `List<T>`. If needed, just cast it:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
IList ilist = (IList)list;
```

Answer (score 10):

To clarify the other answers:

`IList<T>` does *not* require an implementing type to also implement `IList`. `IEnumerable<T>` does require `IEnumerable`.  We can get away with that with `IEnumerable<T>` because a sequence of T can always be treated as a sequence of objects.  But a list of giraffes cannot be treated as a list of objects; you can add a tiger to a list of objects.

However, `List<T>` does *unsafely* implement `IList`. If you try to add a tiger to a `List<Giraffe>` by first casting it to IList, you'll get an exception.

So to answer the question: If all you have in hand is an `IList<T>`, you can speculatively cast it to `IList` with the "as" operator, and if that fails, then create a new `ArrayList` or `List<object>` and copy the contents in. If what you have in hand is a `List<T>` then you already have something that implements `IList` directly.

Comment: <<...add a tiger to a List<Giraffe>...you'll get an exception.>> not to mention a nasty mess. --appreciate the objectification -vHelpful.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do any conversion at all. A `List<T>` implements the `IList` interface.

If you need the type `IList` for example to use a specific overload, just use the cast syntax `(IList)theList`.